# To what extent the Laplace transform of the function $x^q$ is justified when $-1<q<0$?

Tags: laplace-transform, integral-transforms

The (one-sided) Laplace transform of the function $x^q$ [according to the tables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_transform#Table_of_selected_Laplace_transforms) is ${\operatorname {\Gamma } (q+1) \over s^{q+1}}$. According to the tables, it is valid for $q>-1$. Other tables though seem to exclude the non-integer cases. But my calculations show problems with $-1<q<0$ as well. Thus I wonder, to what extent the formula is justified at (non-integer) $-1<q<0$?

Comment: What were the problems you found with $-1 < q  < 0$?

Comment: When $q>-1$, then the function $x^q$ is integrable near 0.

Comment: @CrackedBauxite so, what does it mean? Why is this important?

Comment: This implies that the integral defining the laplace transform exists.

Comment: @CrackedBauxite okay, but how can we be sure that the formula given in the tables is correct? Specifically, for non-integer $q$?